# Reducing database calls

Tags: entity-framework, database-performance, iqueryable

What would be the best way to do this in 1 DB call?

```
if (dbContext.Owners.Any(i => i.Value == dog.OwnerID)) //Check if owner exists in db
{
    //Assign the owner's contact number to the dog entry
    dbDog.OwnerContactNumber = dbContext.Owners.First(i => i.Value == dog.OwnerID).ContactNumber; 
}
```

My thoughts:

```
Owner owner = dbContext.Owners.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Value == dog.OwnerID); //Get the owner
if (owner)
{
    dbDog.OwnerContactNumber = owner.ContactNumber; //Assign the contact number
}
```

But it feels bad having to declare that extra owner variable. And I have a bunch of these if statements, so I'll have to create a bunch of extra unneeded owner variables.

How can I do this better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have to check if you can get an owner's `ContactNumber` from the database, not the entire owner, because you don't update it. And you can even do it without using a "needless" variable:

```
dbDog.OwnerContactNumber = 
     dbContext.Owners
              .Where(i => i.Value == dog.OwnerID)
              .Select(o => o.ContactNumber)
              .FirstOrDefault() ?? dbDog.OwnerContactNumber;
```

So if no owner number is found, no change is made.